# PostSharp Error With Express Edition

Tags: msbuild, postsharp

I'm seeing errors using PostSharp Express

```
(PostSharp30 target) ->
  Core.csproj : postsharp error PS0127: The assembly 'ModuleDeclaration Utilities.dll' uses non-licensed features (
Basic Features). Please visit http://www.postsharp.net/purchase to acquire a license of PostSharp.
  Core.csproj : postsharp error PS0154: Information regarding the previous message: the installed user license is: "".
  Core.csproj : postsharp error PS0060: The processing of module "Core.dll" was not successful.
```

AFAICT, my installation is good, but there were no values written in to the registry under `HKCU/SOFTWARE/SharpCrafters/PostSharp 3/LicenseKey`

I've tried everything I can find to fix this to no avail so far.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In my specific case, I don't have VisualStudio installed since this is all running on a build server.  From PostSharp support:

without Visual Studio, you can access the registration dialog via %ProgramData%\PostSharp\\bin.Release\PostSharp.HQ.v3.0.exe if you have PostSharp 4.3.x or via %ProgramData%\PostSharp\\bin.Release\PostSharp.Settings.UI.exe.

Using this tool, you can register the Express license again.